# Keep the selection check mark after page refresh

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

This is code for dropdown function with href. When I select an item in the drop down a tick mark icon should appear. When I click the href, the page loads and the selection is gone. Is there a way to make the visibility status remains even after the reload?

```js
$('#submitDropdown > a').click(function(e) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#submitDropdown  > a').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});

$('#sort_descend > a').click(function(e) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#sort_descend  > a').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
#submitDropdown>a>.fas {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#submitDropdown>a.selected>.fas {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="submitDropdown" class="dropdown-content " style="width: 180px;">
  <a  class="dropdown-item borderbottom " href="@Url.AddQueryString(Request.RawUrl, "Modes", "All" )">
    @T("All")  
    <i class="fas fa-check pull-right"></i> 
  </a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.AddQueryString(Request.RawUrl, "Modes", "Current" )">
    @T("Current") 
    <i class="fas fa-check pull-right"></i>
  </a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.AddQueryString(Request.RawUrl, "Modes", "For" )">
    @T("For") 
    <i class="fas fa-check pull-right"></i> 
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, it is possible using some kind of storage, where you store the checked value and loads it on page load. For example, [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) or [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: I understood the process of storage. If possible, can you please add an example for the above case using sessionStorage or localStorage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use localStorage or Session storage:
Below is the implementation for local storage.

```
$('#submitDropdown > a').click(function(e) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#submitDropdown  > a').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  localStorage.setItem('submitDropdown', 'selected');
});

$('#sort_descend > a').click(function(e) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#sort_descend  > a').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  localStorage.setItem('sort_descend', 'selected');
});
```

This will allow you to set the flag for each item.
Link for your reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

After refreshing the page, you can add the 'selected' class after reading from local storage.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 if(localStorage.getItem('submitDropdown') === 'selected'){
   $('#sort_descend  > a').addClass('selected');
 }
});
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but it doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: Once user clicks on dropdown, the value will be set in localStorage. So, when you refresh the page then you need to read the value from localStorage: localStorage.getItem('submitDropdown') and add 'selected' class

Comment: it still doesn't work. It may be something with my rest of the code. Thanks for the idea though..

Comment: Can you please upvote my answer for the idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your idea works. I hade to make some tweaks to make it work. Thanks again